# How we can change Asp.net_Sessionid After login the application

Tags: asp.net, session, session-cookies

Our application is using **asp.net_sessionId** to maintain user session on the browser.
However, our requirement is to change the value of **asp.net_sessionId** after user logs in.

Could you please help on how to do this.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/143302). What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: One of our clients ran a security audit against our web site.  The issues they reported is When the user goes to our web site, it creates a session and sets a session ID in a cookie.  When the user logs in, instead of changing the session ID now that the user has been authenticated, the session ID remains the same.  This is considered a security flaw to use the same session ID after authentication.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c2c16cb-2a7e-4edb-a814-80c70bbe2f8b/how-to-change-aspnet-sessionid-after-login-?forum=aspgettingstarted

There's a link which discuss the issue, however I want to know if there's any other way.

Comment: Did you explore [Custom Session Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100)#custom-session-identifiers) and if [Cookieless SessionIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100)#cookieless-sessionids) may solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out.